# Why the li tag not getting the value of loop variable?

Tags: node.js, express, pug, jade4j

I am trying to loop through the object that is coming from app.js. I am using each loop in PUG/JADE, so that I can use its value to print some values. But the li is not getting the value of loop variable

**Note :**  I am getting 'post.title' and 'post.body' below 4 times because, it's coming from the mongo database and I did exactly 4 entries in the database. Plus this also means that object is correctly coming to the index page, but li is not getting the value of loop variable.

**Output I am getting**

```
 . = post.title
 . = post.body
 . = post.title
 . = post.body
 . = post.title
 . = post.body
 . = post.title
 . = post.body
```

**What I want**

```
 Title of the post
 body of the post

 Title of another post
 Body of another post

 and so on....
```

**My Code**

---- index.pug ----

```
block content
    ul
    each post in posts
        li = post.title
        li = post.body
```

---- app.js ----

```
let Post = require('./models/post');

app.get('/', function(req, res){
   Post.find({}, function(err, posts){

   if(err){
       console.log(err);
   } else {
      res.render('index', {   
        title:'Posts',
        posts: posts
     });
   }
 });
});
```

**What Else I tried**

I made a constant array just above the loop to check and iterated through that array. But it gave me the same result as

```
. = name
. = name
. = name
```

don't know why. The code for that is below.

```
block content
     - const names = ["Sami", "Abeer", "Hassaan"];
     ul.list-group
         each name in names
            li = name
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the space between `li =`, so you get `li= name`. The space indicates that the equal sign should be content of the tag.

Full example of your index.pug:

```
block content
    ul
    each post in posts
        li= post.title
        li= post.body
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly. Don't know why they would not allow space before = sign. it's my programming style to give space before = sign.

Comment: Understable. It's just a pug thing. So you can do: 

h1 My Super cool header

Thats why
h1 = <- This is an equal sign

would be a string. While:

h1= <- this will crash because it expects javascript now